# Swift Framework with Cocoa Pods

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have created custom swift framework in this I have installed pods for using some third party framework.

I am done with the successful build now but How I can use or add that framework in my existing project.

Do I need to copy the entire framework project in my existing project?

If any one knows the solution please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same problem and here's what I did

1. Open the custom framework you are creating, under products section in the navigation bar right click on the your custom framework (eg customFramework.framework) file and select "reveal in finder".
2. Now along with your custom framework you can see all the third party frameworks you are using. Copy all the frameworks you need and paste them wherever you feel like so you can easily access to them.
3. Now open up your existing project where you want to use your custom framework.
4. Go to Embedded Binaries section in the general tab of your target. Click on the + button -> click on add other -> navigate to location where you pasted all your required frameworks along with your custom framework and click open.

That's it. Do this and let me know if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

- Build your framework and copy from Product. As shown in screenshot CyptoAPI.framework

[image]

- Drag into you existing project and also add into Embedded Binaries.

[image]

Hope this will help.

Comment: But I have installed pod in my Custom Framework so do I need to add xcworkspace file in my existing project?

Comment: No just framework as shown in screenshot, thats the output for your complete project.

Comment: It is saying "framework not found" after adding that custom framework in existing project

Comment: Have you added framework in Embedded Binaries in your application

Answer (score 1):

1. In your main project click with right click and select "Add files to yourProject.."
2. Then you add the file .xworkspace of your framework, so you can modify from there parts of code.
3. After that go on the General page of Xcode, when you can select deployement Target, devices etc..
   Go down until you see the section of **Embedded Binaries**, click on the button + and add the framework you added before with the command "Add files to yourProject.." in part 1

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious, easiest and manageable solution would be [creating a pod](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html). Then declare the required pods in `xyz.podspec` file to use your pod as dependencies.

Use your custom cocoapod using following:

```
pod 'Name', :path => '~/code/Pods/' # if in local file system
pod 'NAME', :git => 'https://example.com/URL/to/repo/NAME.git' # if it is in your private repo
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without creating pods?

Comment: Yes there is, but the way is pretty hard. You have to copy all the framework needed and in case of different architecture build, you may have to re-build the frameworks for particular that architecture. If you want to avoid architecture mismatch you have to create fat-library to bind all the architecture support into one framework.

Comment: And the last part i forgot to put, if you want to integrate the same framework in another project, you have to go through the same procedure, each time you try to integrate it to a new project.